# Hikari CP - Continuosly Validate Idle Connections

Tags: connection-pooling, hikaricp

I observed that Hikari validates the connection before giving it to the requester. At that point, if the connection is found to be dead, a new connection is created.

Is there a way that idle connections are regularly validated (even if no one is asking for a new connection)?

Something similar is present in C3P0 as 'idle_test_period'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define [keepaliveTime](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) to validate idle connections

> "keepalive" will only occur on an idle connection. When the time arrives for a "keepalive" against a given connection, that connection will be removed from the pool, "pinged", and then returned to the pool. The 'ping' is one of either: invocation of the JDBC4 isValid() method, or execution of the connectionTestQuery.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I was using version 3.x in which this option is not available.